# binding PDO mysql parameter from $_get doesn't work

Tags: php, binding, get, pdo, parameter-passing

```
// url: http://localhost/asdf/?sort=credits


if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
    $sort = $_GET['sort'];
}

$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY :sort");
$statement->bindParam(':sort', $sort, PDO::PARAM_STR, 8);

var_dump($statement);
//object(PDOStatement)[2] public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY :sort' (length=36)

$statement->execute();
```

Im trying to an ordering option from the get parameters, can anyone help me out?

**update**
as suggest by @Uchiha Madara, i created some predifed ordering strings

```
if(isset($_GET['sort'])){
    switch ($_GET['sort']){
        case 'val1':
            $sortName = 'val1';
            break;
        case 'val2':
            $sortName = 'val2';
            break;

        default:
            $sortName = false;
            break;
    }
}

if($sortname != false){
    // then prepare query
    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY ?");
    $statement->execute(array($sortName));
}
```

but still same result, ordering choice is ignored

**last update!**

```
$sort = 'val1';

$orderList = array(
    'val1',
    'val2'
);

// then prepare query
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY $sort");
$statement->execute();
```

thank @Madara Uchiha and @Ray!

Comment: the query executes but there is no ordering applied

Comment: Do you mean to use `$order`? Or `$sort`, as that's the variable you're creating...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Maybe because you named you variable `$sort`, but you're trying to bind `$order`?</s>

That's because you can't bind column names with prepared statements. They're only meant to be used with values.

Instead, what you should do, is to have a set of predefined options, and sort by those. You shouldn't give the user a choice of directly ordering by a real column name.

Comment: @AdonisK.: Yes, a very strict white-list.

Answer (score 3):

See Madra's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12585182/212940).

You can't bind a column.  Use a white list array of valid columns to sort against (to compare the $_GET value to) and just substitute it into the query:

```
$valid_cols = array('name', 'age');
$sort = 'default_sort_field';
if(isset($_GET['sort']) && in_array($_GET['sort'], $valid_cols)){
    $sort = $_GET['sort'];
}

$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY $sort");
```

Comment: @AdonisK. Ah, rookie mistake--I overlooked your use of binding, I updated my answer based on Madra's note below.